# How to add field into class with deserialization compatibility using Protostuff?

Tags: java, protostuff

I have an immutable object of class

```
class A {
   public A(B b) {
       this.a = b.c;
   }

   @Tag(1)
   final int a;
}
```

How to add field into class with backward binary deserialization compatibility using Protostuff without writing custom deserializers if it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Always append new fields in your class rather than insert them in the middle of the fields.

refer to [official document](https://protostuff.github.io/docs/protostuff-runtime/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).